# Dynamically select Nodes in Xpath in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, xpath

I have following XML to parse  in SQL Server 2008

```
<Root>
  <Document>
    <Body>
      <Component>
      </Component>
    </Body>
  </Document>
</Root>
```

I want to retrieve all the `<Component>` tags in my xml, the issue is that `<Document>` tag at times might not come, Hence my xpath query of (root/document/body) won't work. Is there way I can get all `<Component>` tags irrespective of presence of `<Document>` tag?

Answer (score 2):

You could always use an XPath query of

```
//component
```

to get all `<component>` elements in your entire document - no matter where they are and what other tags there are around it

Comment: Or like this if you want to be a little bit more specific. `/Root//Body/Component`